# Make This `for loop` to a Function

Tags: javascript

This Code Read & Send JSON File Documents
How Can I Make This Code to a **Function** and call That in 1 Line?

```
  //  sendAllDocument
  var i,j,tempstring;
  for (i=0,j=locale.keyboards[msg.text].document.length; i<j; i++) {
      tempstring = locale.keyboards[msg.text].document[i];
      bot.sendDocument(msg.chat.id, tempstring, opts);
  }
```

Comment: You know how to make a for-loop but not a function...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function sendAllDocument(msg, opts) {
    var i,j,tempstring;
    for (i=0,j=locale.keyboards[msg.text].document.length; i<j; i++) {
        tempstring = locale.keyboards[msg.text].document[i];
        bot.sendDocument(msg.chat.id, tempstring, opts);
    }
}
```

**To call:**

```
sendAllDocument(msg, opts);
```

Comment: Cannot find name 'opts'

Comment: I've updated the code to allow you to pass in opts to the function.

Comment: Solved. Thank you. @diderdrogba344

Comment: np, glad I can help!

Answer (score 2):

```
function sendAllDocument(){
  var i,j,tempstring;
  for (i=0,j=locale.keyboards[msg.text].document.length; i<j; i++) {
      tempstring = locale.keyboards[msg.text].document[i];
      bot.sendDocument(msg.chat.id, tempstring, opts);
  }
}
```

and call it `sendAllDocument()`

Comment: How Can I Use that?

Comment: Cannot find name 'opts'

Answer (score 0):

Create a function:

```
function sendAll(msg, opts, bot) {
    locale.keyboards[msg.text].document.forEach(function (document) {
        bot.sendDocument(msg.chat.id, document, opts);
    };
};
```

and execute it:

```
sendAll(msg, opts, bot);
```